# How to find duplicate values in a list and merge them

Tags: python, list, merge, duplicates, nested-lists

So basically for example of you have a list like:

```
l = ['a','b','a','b','c','c']
```

The output should be:

```
[['a','a'],['b','b'],['c','c']]
```

So basically put together the values that are duplicated into a list,

I tried:

```
l = ['a','b','a','b','c','c']
it=iter(sorted(l))
next(it)
new_l=[]
for i in sorted(l):
   new_l.append([])
   if next(it,None)==i:
      new_l[-1].append(i)
   else:
      new_l.append([])
```

But doesn't work, and if it does work it is not gonna be efficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort the list then use `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> l = ['a','b','a','b','c','c']
>>> [list(g) for _, g in groupby(sorted(l))]
[['a', 'a'], ['b', 'b'], ['c', 'c']]
```

EDIT: this is probably not the fastest approach, sorting is O(n log n) time complexity for the average case and not required for all solutions (see the comments)

Comment: This requires an average time complexity of O(n log n), however.

Comment: @blhsing Yes, I know, I'm not actually sure this is the best solution it was just my first thought (one needs to be quick on SO), I will defer judgement to a `timeit` benchmark

Comment: @Chris_Rands It's known that Python's `sorted` function has an average time complexity of O(n log n).

Comment: @blhsing yes you just said that, I agree :)

Comment: Accepted.., didn't realize `itertools.groupby` can do this much :-)

Comment: @U9-Forward Thanks but I'm not convinced this is the best way, Austin or Blhsing's solutions might be faster, and will retain the order if the `OrderedCounter` recipe is added

Comment: @Chris_Rands or if the Python version remembers dict insertion order, i.e. 3.6 and above.

Comment: @timgeb indeed or 3.7 and above for the guarantee across all python implementations

Comment: @timgeb BTW i think the reason I thought of this first and it seems so intuitive is it follow a typical command-line (unix) pattern of `sort | uniq -c`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
[[k] * c for k, c in Counter(l).items()]
```

This returns:

```
[['a', 'a'], ['b', 'b'], ['c', 'c']]
```

### `%%timeit` comparison

- Given a sample dataset of 100000 values, this answer is the fastest approach.

[image]

Comment: Works too, nice

Comment: Note that `Counter()` has an average time complexity of O(n).

Answer (score 4):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

l = ['a','b','a','b','c','c']
c = Counter(l)

print([[x] * y for x, y in c.items()])
# [['a', 'a'], ['b', 'b'], ['c', 'c']]
```

Comment: Works too, nice

Comment: This is the best solution. Easy to read and does not require sorting (if you use a Python version where dicts remember insertion order).

Comment: @timgeb Agreed! Although of course sorting and retaining the insertion order and not always going to produce the same output (although they do for this data); don't know what the OP wants actually for sure

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) solution via [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). As it requires sorting, this will have time complexity O(*n* log *n*).

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

L = ['a','b','a','b','c','c']

res = list(map(list, map(itemgetter(1), groupby(sorted(L)))))

[['a', 'a'], ['b', 'b'], ['c', 'c']]
```

The syntax is cumbersome since Python does not offer native function composition. This is supported by 3rd party library [`toolz`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
from toolz import compose

foo = compose(list, itemgetter(1))
res = list(map(foo, groupby(sorted(L))))
```

Comment: Works too, nice

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use `zip` method.

```
l = ['a','b','a','b','c','c','b','c', 'a']
l = sorted(l)
grouped = [list(item) for item in list(zip(*[iter(l)] * l.count(l[0])))]
```

Output

```
[['a', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'b', 'b'], ['c', 'c', 'c']]
```

Comment: Works too, nice

Answer (score 1):

My solution using list comprehension would be (l is a list):

```
[l.count(x) * [x] for x in set(l)]
```

- *set(l)* will retrieve all the element which appears in l, **without** duplicates
- *l.count(x)* will return the number of times a specific element x appears in a given list *l*
- the *** operator** creates a new list with the elements in a list (in this case, *[x]*) repeated the specified number of times (in this case, *l.count(x)* is the number of times)

Answer (score 0):

```
l = ['a','b','a','b','c','c']

want = []
for i in set(l):
    want.append(list(filter(lambda x: x == i, l)))
print(want)
```

Comment: time complexity O(n**2)

Comment: Works too, nice

Comment: Timgeb you are right, but maybe size/speed des not matter.

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Probably not the most efficient, but this is understandable:

```
l = ['a','b','a','b','c','c']
dict = {}
for i in l:
    if dict[i]:
        dict[i] += 1
    else:
         dict[i] = 1

new = []
for key in list(dict.keys()):
    new.append([key] * dict[key])
```

Comment: This results in a `KeyError` Also, do not use built-in python functions (`dict`) as a variable name.